# Touch screen operations for .NET windows application?

Tags: winforms, touch

We are building a Windows application in .NET and one of its requirements is touch screen monitor. Other than that, it's a normal windows form based application. But except for making UI items little bigger for touch, I can't find anything I as a developer need to do for the requirement since touch screen is basically mouse operations. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you are not missing anything.  Do get the actual hardware hooked up so you can test it, "little bigger" is invariably underestimating the problem of fat fingers.  Everything should work from a single click, right-clicks are horribly impractical, double-clicks are best avoided.

The only other thing you'll want to do is go into the Control Panel + Display applet and change the size of standard Windows UI elements.  Pick a large window caption font if you want to allow the user to drag or close windows.  Make the scrollbars at least twice as wide.  And the menu and message box font.  Go in the Mouse applet to increase double-click range and time if you want to support that.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not need touch-specific event handling I think it's all you have to do. But touch means more than that and you may want to support it in a better way: http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsTouch/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=2127