# Native controls for Windows Forms Application on touch screen?

Tags: .net, windows, winforms, user-interface, touch

TLDR: is there a standard version of winforms' `comboBox` that is touch-friendly?

---

I've been writing a Windows Forms Application that suddenly need to run on a Microsoft Surface Pro (running Windows 10). Since I'm using standard controls (buttons, text fields, drop down lists) I expected them to automatically adapt when I switch to tablet mode (just like, say, explorer's controls become larger and easier to click on). But they don't.

I didn't manage to find a standard implementation for touch-friendly controls. Do I have to implement them myself? Most of all I'm interested in a `comboBox` control, since it can't be simply scaled and its tiny up and down arrows are really hard to target with a finger.

I've seen this [8 year old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9667544/touch-screen-operations-for-net-windows-application), but I do hope things have improved since?

Comment: [Touch Input - Programming Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wintouch/programming-guide) -- [RegisterTouchWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registertouchwindow) -- [Multi-touch Gestures Application](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/master/Samples/Win7Samples/Touch/MTGestures/CS)

Comment: thanks a lot, exactly what I was looking for! (I swear I googled for half an hour before asking and didn't end up anywhere near those pages...)

Comment: I'm not sure you want to get *near those pages*. You'll see... Good luck :)

Comment: why? I want to know what I'm getting myself into XD

Comment: @Jimi wait but all those articles talk about enabling touch input or programming for touch input. I'm mainly interested in controls' appearance. I'll edit my question to better reflect this.